# Powershell run operator and function arguments

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and not quite familiar with all fineries of syntax. And despite having worked through quite some help on the topic, I still can not get this to work:

In my script, I load other ps1 files, depending on inputs, this works fine, e.g:

```
$cmd = "tranlate_$f"  # the full string is the valid name of a function which was dot sourced into this file.
& $cmd
```

However, if I also want to pass that function an argument, this does not get passed, e.g.:

```
$cmd = "tranlate_$f"  # the full string is the valid name of a function which was dot sourced into this file.
$args = @($value1)
& $cmd $args
```

...then no input reaches the functions. I tried various variations of this, inlcuding passing $value1 directly instead of in a list.

What would be the right way of passing it?

Extended example on request:
In some other file:

```
function translateDate {
    param (
        $input
    )

    Write-Debug "translateDate: input: $input"
    if ($input -eq $null) { return "" }

    # YYYYMMDD
    if ($input -match '.*(20\d\d[0-1]\d[0-3]\d).*') {
        Write-Debug "translateDate: YYYYMMDD"
        return $matches[1]
    }
    
    # DD.MM.YYYY
    if ($input -match '([0-3]\d)\.([0-1]\d).(20\d\d)') {
        Write-Debug "translateDate: DD.MM.YYYYY"
        return "$($matches[3])$($matches[2])$($matches[1])"
    }

...omitted other similar sections.

  return $input
}
```

In the main script:

```
$value = "Q32020"
$translator ="Date"
$cmd = "translate$translator"
$argList = @("$value")
$value = & $cmd $argList
```

From the Write-Debug in the translate function I can see that the function is called. $input is empty though. (I know I cut the section that would do the actual translation, but the issue is somewhere else.).
Best,

YeOldHinnerk

Comment: Please show a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (including where you define/assign to `$value1`)

Comment: Can you show us a minimal representation of your function? Also, `$args` is an automatic PS variable you cannot assign values to it.

Comment: Changed var name from $args to $argList, didn't help. But thank you for pointing out it is a reserved variable name.

Comment: `$input` is another automatic variable :)

Comment: Whoa. I did mention, I'm new to it? Thank you, will fix that too and get back.

Comment: Seems to have helped. Thank you!

Comment: The proper way to call your function, once loaded into memory, would be `$value = translateDate -ParamName Q32020` where `ParamName` would be in your `param(..)` block => `param( $paramName )`